# Anyone with an interesting method to prove $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x}\ln\left({1+e^{-x}\over 1-e^{-x}}\right)dx=1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

We wish to prove that

> $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x}\ln\left({1+e^{-x}\over 1-e^{-x}}\right)dx=\color{red}{1}\tag1$$

Apply substitution:

$u=e^{-x}\rightarrow du=-e^{-x}dx$

$x=\infty\rightarrow u=0$, $x=0\rightarrow u=1$

$$I=2\int_{0}^{1}u\tanh^{-1}udu\tag2$$

Recall

$$\int x\tanh^{-1}x dx={x\over 2}+{1\over 2}(x^2-1)\tanh^{-1}x\tag3$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}x\tanh^{-1}x dx={1\over 2}\tag4$$

Sub $(4)$ into $(2)$

Therefore $I=1$

Anyone with an interesting method to prove (1)?

Comment: Interesting as in how?  I think your way is pretty interesting myself ...

Comment: As in different style of approaching this problem.

Comment: $$I\overset{t=e^{-x}}=\int_{0}^{1}\tanh^{-1}t\ d(t^2-1)\overset{ibp}=1$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{I} & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-2x}\ln\pars{1 + \expo{-x} \over 1 - \expo{-x}}\,\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-2x}\,\mathrm{arctanh}\pars{\expo{-x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
2\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-2x}\,
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pars{2n + 1}x} \over 2n + 1}\,\dd x =
2\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over 2n + 1}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{2n + 3}x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
\half\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 3/2}\pars{n + 1/2}} =
\half\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over n + 1/2} - {1 \over n + 3/2}} =
\half\,{1 \over 0 + 1/2} = \color{#f00}{1}
\end{align}

Comment: Q.E.D (+1) @Felix Marin

Comment: @Chinacat Thanks. You are welcome.

Comment: @Algebra Thanks. I'm sorry I didn't read your comment in June !!!.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to show that

\begin{equation}
\ln\left(\!{1+e^{-x}\over 1-e^{-x}}\!\right)=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{e^{-(2n+1)x}\over 2n+1}
\end{equation}

Using the generating function above, the considered integral becomes

\begin{align}
I&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2\over 2n+1}\int_0^\infty e^{-(2n+3)x}\ dx\\[10pt]
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2\over {(2n+1)(2n+3)}}\\[10pt]
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[{1\over{2n+1}}-{1\over {2n+3}}\right]\\[10pt]
&=1
\end{align}
where the latter sum is a telescoping series.

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as Felix's solution?

Answer (score 5):

For a more compact notation, rewrite $\dfrac{1+e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}=\coth\dfrac{x}{2}$. Denote a parameterized form of your integral by
$$\mathcal{I}_s=\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\ln\left(\coth\frac{x}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x$$
which you may observe to be the Laplace transform of $\ln\left(\coth\dfrac{x}{2}\right)$.

It so happens that the transform in this case has an interesting closed form in terms of the [harmonic numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) $H_n$:
$$\mathcal{I}_s=\frac{H_{(s-1)/2}-H_{s/2}+2H_s+\ln4}{2s}$$
(computation courtesy of [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laplace+transform+log(coth(x%2F2)))

The value of your integral is then obtained when $s=2$, i.e.
$$\mathcal{I}_2=\frac{H_{1/2}-H_1+2H_2+\ln4}{4}=\frac{\left(2-2\ln2\right)-1+2\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+\ln4}{4}=1$$
as desired.

Comment: This is a cool one! (+1) @user170231

Answer (score 2):

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2x}\ln\left({1+e^{-x}\over 1-e^{-x}}\right)dx=\left[\tfrac{1}{2}\ln\left(\tfrac{1+e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\right)\left(1-e^{-2x}\right)-e^{-x}\right]_0^{\infty}=0-(-1)=\boxed{1}$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^\infty e^{-2x} \log\left(\frac{1+e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}\right) \, dx \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^1 (1-y) \log\left(\frac{2-y}y\right) \, dy \tag{1} \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^1 dy \tag{2} \\[1ex]
&= \boxed{1}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $y=1-e^{-x}$
- $(2)$ : integrate by parts